# CakePHP: hook to query database at beginning of request

Tags: database, cakephp, orm

I'd like to set some global parameters in CakePHP based on data in the database. Where in my app can I add some code to query the database as early as possible in the request? It needs to be after the database config is set up, but before other queries run.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform some logic before a particular Controller action is executed then override the [Controller::beforeFilter method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Controller.html#_beforeFilter).

On the other hand, if you want to do some logic globally, then define a [AppController](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) and do your logic in beforeFilter.

In either case, don't forget to parent::beforeFilter();

Also, as a general reminder, here is the [request cycle](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html#cakephp-request-cycle)

[image]